# Destructure Array using entries and iterator

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. Each object has got the same properties. I try to create a function to return an array of arrays where each inside array should contain values based on objects' property names.

Input:

```
input: [
    {
       test1: '10',
       test2: '15',
       test3: '14',
       test4: '22'
    },
    {
       test1: '4',
       test2: '1',
       test3: '45',
       test4: '2'
    },
    {
       test1: '5',
       test2: '16',
       test3: '7',
       test4: '0'
    }
]
```

Expected output - inside array contains only elements whose keys are the same.
For example  `test1` values in an array: `[10, 4, 5]`:

```
output: [[10, 4, 5], [15, 1, 16], [14, 45, 7], [22, 2, 0]]
```

My approach is to use array.entries() and iterator. The result is wrong - values are stored in the wrong order.

```
let output = [];
sort(input) {
    const results = [[], [], [], []];
    if (input.length > 0) {
      const iterator = input.entries();
      let item = iterator.next();
      while (!item.done) {
        const data = Object.values(item.value[1]);
        results.forEach((result, index) => {
          if (item.value[0] == index)
            result.push(parseFloat(data[index]));
        });
        item = iterator.next();
      }
    }
    output = results;
  }
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: How do you want to specify the order of the output?  Just whatever happens to be the order of, say, the first object in your array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one technique, which just uses the key-order of the first object to determine the final output order:

```js
const restructure = (input = []) => 
  Object .keys (input [0] || {}) 
    .map (k => input .map (x => x [k]))

const input = [{test1: '10', test2: '15', test3: '14', test4: '22'}, {test1: '4', test2: '1', test3: '45', test4: '2'}, {test1: '5', test2: '16', test3: '7', test4: '0'}]

console .log (restructure (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We simply extract the shared keys from the first object and use that to determine what to extract from each of them.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: Awesome solution !

Comment: This is mind blowing that the solution is a one-liner, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```js
let input = [{
    test1: '10',
    test2: '15',
    test3: '14',
    test4: '22'
  },
  {
    test1: '4',
    test2: '1',
    test3: '45',
    test4: '2'
  },
  {
    test1: '5',
    test2: '16',
    test3: '7',
    test4: '0'
  }
]

// initialize result array
let result = [...Array(Object.keys(input[0] || {}).length)].map(x => []);
// fill object
input.forEach(val => {
  // push each value into the according position in the result array.
  Object.values(val).forEach((val, i) => {
    result[i].push(val)
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. But I wouldn't have that approach, I'd rather use much less "stuff", like so.
I don't get why the function is named "sort", there is no sort!

```js
"use strict";

function sort(data)
{
  var stacks, stacknames;

  stacks = [];
  stacknames = {};

  data.forEach(item => {
    var k;

    for (k in item)
    {
      if (!(k in stacknames))
      {
        stacknames[k] = stacks.length; // map name to index
        stacks.push([]); // allocate new stack
      }

      stacks[stacknames[k]].push(parseFloat(item[k]));
    }
  });

  return stacks;
}

var input = [
    {
       test1: '10',
       test2: '15',
       test3: '14',
       test4: '22'
    },
    {
       test1: '4',
       test2: '1',
       test3: '45',
       test4: '2'
    },
    {
       test1: '5',
       test2: '16',
       test3: '7',
       test4: '0'
    }
];

var output = sort(input);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested loop can give you the expected result as follows.

```js
let input = [
    {
       test1: '10',
       test2: '15',
       test3: '14',
       test4: '22'
    },
    {
       test1: '4',
       test2: '1',
       test3: '45',
       test4: '2'
    },
    {
       test1: '5',
       test2: '16',
       test3: '7',
       test4: '0'
    }
];

const getValues = (data) => {
  // Get keys in the object
  let keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
  // Initialize the result with empty arrays
  let temp = [...Array(Object.keys(data[0] || {}).length)].map(x => []);

  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<keys.length; j++) {
      let str = keys[j];
      temp[j].push(data[i][str]);
    }
 }
 console.log(temp);
}

getValues(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simple when we make use of `reduce`.

```js
var input=[ { test1: '10', test2: '15', test3: '14', test4: '22' }, { test1: '4', test2: '1', test3: '45', test4: '2' }, { test1: '5', test2: '16', test3: '7', test4: '0' }];

var result = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  Object.entries(elem).forEach(([k,v])=>{
    acc[k] = acc[k] || [];
    acc[k].push(v);
  })
  return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result)
```